# How to test international numbers between Twilio and a service like TextMagic

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to set up our app to send SMS with Twilio. The person who does a lot of our testing lives overseas, so I need to obtain a US phone number that she can use so she can do her testing. I got a number via TextMagic, but when I try to add it to the list of verified numbers on my Twilio dashboard, the verification code (seemingly) never gets sent to the TextMagic number. Is there some sort of restriction on Twilio's side regarding numbers generated from services like TextMagic? Any info would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm not aware of anything that would necessarily restrict things between Twilio and TextMagic.

Can I suggest using another Twilio number to test things? It does work to send between Twilio numbers and you'll need the same knowledge to setup the Twilio number as to use it as a test number.